# Create several filesystemwatcher (and its event handlers) at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-2.0

I've this scenario: a user of my service application wants to configure in a xml configuration file a list of n paths.
At startup time I want to create n filesystemwatcher with their eventhandler.

How to do this?

Is really simple in vs to create FileSystemWatcher, but how to do this when I don't know how many?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check out this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mokhtarb2005/FSWatcherMB12052005063103AM/FSWatcherMB.aspx. There is also a CodeProject article about [Using FileSystemWatcher to monitor multiple directories](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271669/Using-FileSystemWatcher-to-monitor-multiple-direct). Also, check out the related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716401/monitor-multiple-folders-using-filesystemwatcher.

Comment: what was the end solution you went with?

Answer (score 1):

Creating FSW instance for each path would be Expensive, i would suggest to go with root directory. eg. C:\ or D:\, then filter out the path which is not required.

For example,

Create FSW for C:\

if you want to monitor only C:\Windows\System32, ignore events other than System32 path. this way you can do what you expect...

Comment: Hi, I thought at a solution like this, but wouldn't be more expensive in this way, wasting (in my case) the 99% of the events? In my situation the "n" is usually 3 or 4, no more

Comment: in this case, you can have a Lazy List in memory  of size predefined and create objects for the list on demand